# How to select customly shaped areas of an image?

Tags: android

Is it possible to detect clicks on previously defined areas of an image?

Example:

[image]

So in other words, is it possible to define borders of shapes dynamically? Or is it necessary to hard code them? Is there any other possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I thought about it for some time and its a bit of a hack but you can achieve what you want by modifying the image. Use any image editing software to color each region slightly differently (this should be easy, just use paint fill). Just use a color that is very close to white so that it is not noticeable to the people who are looking at the image. Then put the image inside an imageview and add a touch listener.

```
final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();

        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

        int red = Color.red(pixel);
        int blue = Color.blue(pixel);
        int green = Color.green(pixel);     
        int alpha = Color.alpha(pixel);        

        //use these information to see which region you have selected
        //if the color is black, then you know you selected the boundary

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use touch position and map to your custom shaped areas

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    }

    return false;
}
```

The three cases are so that you can react to different types of events, in this example tapping or dragging or lifting the finger again.

Also, you can use different images for the same.